# Jquery ajax call within the success function of another ajax call not working and not telling the type of error correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an ajax call within the success of another ajax call.
This is working perfectly in `localhost` but not on the server.

Here's what I am doing.

```
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {  
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                     url:"http://gagsterz.com/index.php/home/InsertUser",
                     data:{id: response.id,name:response.name,at:self.access_token},
                     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    $('#error').html(xhr.responseText);
  },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            FB.api('/me/friends',function(response) {
                                if(response.data) 
                                {
                                    countfriends = 0;
                                    filedata="";
                                    self.friendsID = new Array();
                                    self.friendsName = new Array();

                                    $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {

                                        filedata+=friend.id+"\t"+friend.name+"\t"+self.UID+"\n";
                                        countfriends++;

                                        self.friendsID.push(friend.id);
                                        self.friendsName.push(friend.name);
                                    });

                        if($.trim(data)=="InsertFriends")
                        {

                            $.ajax({
                                    url:"http://gagsterz.com/index.php/home/InsertFBFriends",
                                    type:"POST",
                                    data: {fdata : filedata },
                                    success:function(r)
                                    {
                                        alert("success");
                                    },
                                     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);                                      },
                                });

                        }
                          });

               });
```

Now when I click the button.The first ajax call`(parent)` works fine and returns me `InsertFriends` as answer from the php script.Now the ajax request present in the if condition of `InsertFriends` does not work correctly and the `xhr.responseText` is empty string. Now I don't know why it is not working properly. To make it simple I just echoed `abc` on the server side script but I don't know whats wrong with this.

I get the following error in the `Chrome Network Tab`.

[image]

So why it is not working ?

Comment: Try creating a separate function and put function name as the success.

Comment: ok I tried it. Your suggestion worked once and the next time I tried it gave the same error and now it is giving me errors again it worked only once.

Comment: Sorry I do not have access to the source code in which I've solved a similar problem. I'm surprised that it worked once, then stopped. I'm thinking the problem may lie somewhere else. Is the response code 200 ok?

Comment: It says `canceled` and it is giving the error in the jquery file.

Comment: I will keep trying if you get access to that code please let me know and thnx for the help.

Comment: Have you tried defining the dataType you are expecting from the response? http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Comment: You are also not matching braces. You have 13 open brace but 10 closing brace.

Comment: the braces problem is here only.It is correct in my file but still not working.I've tried the data type suggestion but still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the requesttype from `POST` to `GET` and it worked.